# OS X: Running both ethernet and wireless with different networks

Tags: macos, network

I'm in a corporate LAN situation where I have a wireless LAN that will give me access to the outside work, but no access to the corporate servers and a Corporate Ethernet which will give me access to the corporate servers but not the outside world. As I need both to do my job I'm endlessly switching networks or turning wireless on and off to get things done.

I've been looking into how I can run both wireless and ethernet together and have DNS work across both, but I'm struggling to understand how to set it up.

I think I may be able to do it using `/etc/resolver/` files, but so far all I've been able to do is hang my requests rather than get resolving errors back.

Has anyone solved this situation and how?

Comment: How will you choose which subnet destinations go through WiFi and which go through ethernet? You’re mostly at the mercy of your network admin setting up different subsets and DNS to resolve default routes to support your split traffic intention.

Comment: Thats one of the problems. I've also been considering whether to try a script based approach where I manipulate the routing table of the system to direct traffic to specific interfaces. But that seems more clumsy than trying the resolver approach. Plus I don' think it handles DNS. What surprises me the most is that I've encountered this problem at a number of corporate sites, yet very few answers online.

Comment: Sadly, the most complete solution would be to WiFi Out and get a split tunnel vpn in. Unless you’ll acquiesce and just not use the internet at work when work makes it os hard to internet.